# How do I use ZF2 regex validators within the factory pattern

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, zend-framework2

Is anyone familiar with the use of ZF2 regex validators within the factory pattern?

I have taken this code from various blogs and other stackoverflow questions, but it does not seem to work.

The addition of the regex validator blocks all changes to my form from updating the database - so the validator must be failing even when I insert a number.

However, when I check

```
$form -> getMessages();
```

I get an empty array. Any insight would be appreciated.

To illustrate I use a very simple regex that, as I understand it, would block any entry character that is not a number.

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'Number',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'max'      => 20,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Regex',
                'options' => array(
                    'pattern' => '/^[0-9]+$',
                    'messages' => array(
                        'Invalid input, only 0-9 characters allowed'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, Regex validator should sit inside "validators" array...